# Return the last modified date of an Options page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm using Wordpress and ACF / Advanced Custom Fields to add various fields related to my contact OPTIONS page. I need to retrieve the date the the last time the "UPDATE" button was hit.

I have tried to sue the the_modified_date(); but this give me the date the actual contact page post-type was last updated and not the OPTIONS page was

My ACF field setting rules:
Show this field of OPTIONS PAGE is equal to CONTACT

The OPTIONS page is a plugin, so i can add all the ACF fields to the plugin instead of to a page.
Code used for adding the options page:

`if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
        $contactOrder = get_field('about_order', 'option') + 2;
        acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Contact',
        'menu_title'    => 'Contact',
        'menu_slug'     => 'tsum-contact',
        'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect'      => false,
        'icon_url'      => 'dashicons-info',
        'position'      => $contactOrder
    ));
   }`

Code to show modified date of a page, but not what i want:

`<?php the_modified_date(); ?>`

My end goal is to use this time stamp for further calculations, but I just need help to get the timestamp.

Thank you.

[image: Screenshot of my Options Page]

Comment: What do you mean by your "contact OPTIONS" page? Is this a page entitled "Options," or some kind of specialized page, or does the have something to do with backend ACF Options page?

Comment: ACF data is stored as metadata. Have you tried to get the right post meta? I think there’s a updated time stamp there.

Comment: @CKMacLeod I edited my question to with more detail about the OPTIONS page. It is like a settings page, and all the data entered there are saved in wp_options table.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo Since it is an options page, there are now post meta. For instance, this is how I will display a field value: `$email = get_field('contact_email', 'option');  echo $email;`

Comment: Ok so use get_option to retrieve the entry in the options table. ACF stores data in proper WP tables so don’t forget you can always just use the WP way.